# How to access imported functions dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import

I import several files with similar names. They have the same use case but they work differently and I call them depending on other variables.

```js
import * as aAdjustSize from './a/adjustSize'
import * as bAdjustSize from './b/adjustSize'
```

Each file consists of functions like adjustWidth, adjustHeight, ...

How am I able to call these functions dynamically?

In objects I can call a value by using brackets i.e. size["a"].width. Unfortunately it is not that easy for functions.

Something like this would be great:

```js
const model = "a"

[model + "AdjustSize"].adjustWidth()
```

Comment: Store both imports in a map and use that. `const lkp = {aAdjustSize, bAdjustSize}; lkp[model + 'AdjustSize'].adjustWidth()`

Comment: It works beautifully. Thank you!!